# Pointwise convergence of Fourier series of $f\in L^1[0,2\pi]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

A corollary in Katznelson's book page 21 says that:

> If the Fourier series of $f\in L^1[0,2\pi]$ converges on a set $E$ of positive measure, its sum coincides with $f$ almost everywhere on $E$.

Could anyone clarify the details?

Comment: Do you want clarification as to the details of why the corollary holds or would you like clarification on what the statement means?

Comment: Of course, the details of the proof.

Comment: Then, given that Katznelson thinks of it as a corollary, it would help if you also stated the result from which it allegedly follows.

Comment: The only thing that seems to me possibly unclear is that convergence implies summabiliy: If $s_n(f,t)\to $ then 4\sigma_n(f,t0\to 1$. If you know that then it really is immediate from the theorem on p. 20.

Comment: @ Ullrich, Okay but the theorem on P.20 says that  $F_n*f$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere! and no proof has been given (where $F_n$ is the Fejer Kernel). I did not get it.

Comment: The theorem proves that $F_n*f\to f$ at every point where 3.8 holds, so this happens almost everywhere if 3.8 holds almost everywhere. At the bottom of p.19 he gives a reference for the fact that 3.8 does hold almost everywhere. (If you don't want to dive into Zygmund note that 3.8 almost everywhere is essentially just the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, which must be in the book you used when you took reals...)

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich, Thanks a lot for your pay attention. There is something concerning the relation (3.8) that I can not get it. It will be great if you let me continue the discussion by Email, Skype or ...